# ajax sql reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "news" feed for internal staff that works similar to the facebook feed.  When the facebook feed as new updates from mysql it looks as though the div reloads and pushes down and load the most recent updates.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this in (jquery) or javascript.  Any thoughts on pushing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery. I think Following article will help you:

- [How to implement a Post-to-Wall Facebook-like using PHP and jQuery](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-implement-post-to-wall-facebook.html)

If I understand your problem then you need something like this:

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WX7RL/) (You can get news from database instead of textbox)

Comment: The basic concept is what i'm looking for.  Just have to add the ajax call that queries to see if there is a new mysql entry then pushes the append?

Comment: I think you can use **jQuery Timer Plugin** to check your database for specific interval of time. http://jquery.offput.ca/every/

Comment: You can use **jQuery.ajax()** to call a script that return news from your database and place them in DIVs as mentioned in answer.